# Python showing me error of " No module named gTTS ."

Tags: macos-catalina, python-3.7, gtts

I wanted to create python code for Voice Assistance which will use gTTS. 
I ran the code but it didn't work as it showed me,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/niallquadros/Desktop/voiceassistant.py", line 1, in `<module>`
>       from gTTS import gTTS
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gTTS'

Instead, it should have given me the result, and act as a voice assistant.

This was my code which I had written on MacBook Air 2019 on python (3.7.4)

```
from gTTS import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import webbrowser
import satplib

def talkToMe(audio):
    print (audio)
    tts = gTTs(text=audio, lang='en')
    tts.save('audio.mp3')
    os.system('mpg123 audio.mp3')

#Listen for commands
def myCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('I am ready for your next command')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 1)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said: ' + command + '/n')

    #loop back to continue to listen for commands

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        assistant(myCommand())

    return command

#if statesments for executing commands
def assistant(command):

    if 'open Reddit python' in command:
        chrome_path = '/user/bin/google.chrome'
        url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/python'
        webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)

    if 'what\'s up' in command:
        talkToMe('Chillin Bro')

while True:
    assistant(myCommand())
```

In my terminal, it shows me that I have gtts installed already.

```
(base) Nialls-MacBook-Air:~ niallquadros$ pip search gTTS
gTTS (2.1.0)        - gTTS (Google Text-to-Speech), a Python library and CLI
                      tool to interface with Google Translate text-to-speech
                      API
  INSTALLED: 2.1.0 (latest)
Django-Gtts (0.2)   - gTTS google text-to-speech django app
Flask-gTTS (0.12)   - gTTS Google text to speech flask extension
gTTS-token (1.1.3)  - Calculates a token to run the Google Translate text to
                      speech
  INSTALLED: 1.1.3 (latest)
wired-tts (0.2.0)   - "gTTS based Wired story reader."
```

What to do, so that I can execute the code?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  The only line of your code relevant to your question is 'from gTTS import gTTS'; the rest is noise that should be deleted from the question.  Either you did mispelled the import name of the module ('gtts' would be more usual), installed the module for another python installation, or not install the module.  Exactly how did you try to install the module, and if you did, what was the response?

Answer (score 6):

I hope you have first installed the library(Google Text-to-Speech) If not please install it from following command in python:

```
pip install gTTs
```

After you have installed the library its ready to use  in your code be careful about the case of the character.

```
from gtts import gTTs
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from gtts import gTTS
```

Comment: I tried it but still showed the same result as no module named 'gtts' but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from gtts import *
```

It will import everything. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have it installed with the correct pips. So if you're running it with python3 then it needs to be installed on pip3..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
from gTTS import gTTS
```

Write the following command:

```
from gtts import gTTS
```

Comment: I tried it but still showed the same result as no module named 'gtts'

Answer (score 0):

Ah that's because your file is named gtts.py so when you do from gtts import gTTS, Python is trying to import the file you're currently running.

Try renaming your script to something else, should work!

Answer (score 0):

If above answers are not solving your problem then the issue might be about IDE (Integrated Development Environment).

Suppose that if you are using IDE like Anaconda and working on Jupyter notebook then you have to install gtts within the environment of Anaconda.

- Just go to the Anaconda navigator and open CMD.exe Prompt
- type: `pip install gTTS or pip3 install gTTS pyttsx3 playsound`

Now, you can import gtts.